# How to convert a formatted string into plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

User copy paste and send data in following format: " "
I need to convert it into plain txt (we can say ascii chars) like 'jovy debbie'
It comes in different font and format:
ex:
' '
'  '

Any Help will be Appreciated, I already refer other stack overflow question but no luck :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide some code samples?

Comment: So.... Just to clean up your terminology a little, `" "` **IS** a plain string, and it's **NOT** a font. You are correct that these are not ASCII characters, but the other terminology you've used is wrong.

Comment: US-ASCII is a subset of [UTF-8 characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm). What you've been sent is simply non-ASCII characters, which you'd apparently like to map into ASCII characters. However, note that this isn't a very well-defined problem *in general*, because there are some characters with an ambiguous mapping, or even no logical mapping at all, e.g. `Ώ`, `Ԫ`, `֎`, `ؠ`, .....

Comment: Even *emojis*  are valid (possibly combinations of) UTF-8 characters!!

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @TomLord.
Do you have any input  on how to convert it into one common format.
Then later based on common format convert it into as per need.

Comment: What does *" based on common format convert it into as per need"* mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those letters are from the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) block.

Since they have a fixed offset to their ASCII counterparts, you could use [`tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#tr-method) to map them, e.g.:

```
" ".tr("-", "a-z")
#=> "jovy debbie"
```

The same approach can be used for the other styles, e.g.

```
" ".tr("--", "a-zA-Z")
#=> "Jenica Dugos"
```

This gives you full control over the character mapping.

Alternatively, you could try [Unicode normalization](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). The NFKC / NFKD forms should remove most formatting and seem to work for your examples:

```
" ".unicode_normalize(:nfkc)
#=> "jovy debbie"

" ".unicode_normalize(:nfkc)
#=> "Jenica Dugos"
```

Comment: It will not wrok if string is in another format ex: ' '
'  '

Comment: I guess the bigger question is: Why are your users sending obscure unicode characters, and why are you accepting this as valid input if it's now your problem to worry about mapping all input back to ASCII?

Comment: @TomLord I am working on a legacy system and it contains such data in DB so I need to correct it.